# ExtJs 4.2: Radio Button not rendering properly(Button is missing but label is visible)

Tags: extjs, radio-button, extjs4.2, radio-group

I am trying to implement a simple Radio Button in my application(Extjs 4.2). 
But the Radio buttons are not visible. This is my code for generating radio Button(following code is inside Items array of panel):

```
{
    xtype:'form',
    header: false,
    items:[{
        xtype: 'radiogroup',
        fieldLabel: 'Choose',
        items: [
            { boxLabel: 'Option 1', name: 'rb', inputValue: '1' ,inputValue: 'Checked'},
            { boxLabel: 'Option 2', name: 'rb', inputValue: '2' }
        ]
    }]
}
```

This is how it displays it.

[image]

Can someone point out my mistake? Thanks

Comment: need more code. I have tested in [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/16p6) and everything works fine.

Comment: @LightNight Yes, I also tested in fiddle and everything works fine, 
What more should I post here?

Comment: write your full panel code to work with. like this I cannot track problem, maybe problem is in another component layout config. also, which exactly version of Extjs are you using? 4.2.1? look in console: `Ext.versions.extjs.version`

Comment: LightNight Thank you for your time. But @Alexander's solution worked and solved my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS is lacking the radio button styles. So you have to be using Sencha Cmd, because otherwise CSS would be complete.

So let Cmd compile your code once again, then the CSS should be updated accordingly and everything should work.

The uncompiled version of your app still requires the compiled version of CSS, because browsers can't understand the SCSS file format.

Comment: Thank you so much. Like every time, you solution worked like a charm :) 
Thank you for your explanation.