# Extjs 6 useArrows doesn't display arrows

Tags: extjs, extjs6, sencha-cmd

When I set the useArrows property on my Ext.tree.Panel, no arrows show up. Here is the header of my tree.Panel:

```
Ext.define('LifeguardxApp.view.main.pools.PoolsTree', {
extend: 'Ext.tree.Panel',
xtype: 'poolstree',
title: 'Pools',
collapsible: true,
multiSelect: true,
//rowLines: true,

viewModel: {
    type: 'main'
},
controller: 'main',

bind: {
    store: '{pools}'
},
rootVisible: false,
useArrows: true,
...
```

Reading the docs, it doesn't seem like there would be anywhere else that needs configuring in order to show arrows on parent nodes? 
[image]

If any of the other classes or info would be helpful, I am happy to provide. This was an app generated with sencha command.

**UPDATE**
Based on the comments I tried the following:

- Check the fiddle provided by UDID - everything looks fine
- Ceared cache on browser - no fix
- Verified class is required elsewhere - it is
- Inspected DOM element where button should be - Only shows node element, no hidden button
- Checked out the answer suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35845561/extjs-4-2-radio-button-not-rendering-properlybutton-is-missing-but-label-is-vi). Rebuilding did not fix.

I am using the `sencha app watch` command for most development. I am led to believe that this should be fine based on this: [Sencha Command Doc](https://www.sencha.com/blog/using-app-watch/)

I tried `sencha ant sass`, followed by `sencha app refresh`, then `sencha app watch` again, to no avail.

Is there somewhere else that CSS path related info is being set?

**UPDATE 2**

I built a test app using sencha cmd and that had a basic tree in it. The arrows were fine there. Then I copied my current app into that test app, and the arrows disappeared. So now I'm thinking that somehow the tree isn't getting all of the 'treeness' attributes that it should?

Comment: Whatever are you using that is correct. `useArrows: true,` is only the right config.  I created a fiddler for you in which it is fine. https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1imd   You clear your cache and check else see the code placement.

Comment: What happens when you inspect the DOM where the arrow should be?

Comment: If I had to guess - it looks like the tree panel CSS classes aren't being brought in during your build. This may because your class isn't required by anything - only required classes will get brought in during the SASS -> CSS build step.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ExtJs 4.2: Radio Button not rendering properly(Button is missing but label is visible)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35845561/extjs-4-2-radio-button-not-rendering-properlybutton-is-missing-but-label-is-vi)

Comment: Possibly related to this issue? https://www.sencha.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-309512.html?s=26c98d94d89cb6ffddc33e5aa9f9ed25

Answer (score 1):

Not shown in my above code I had a typo in my treecolumn. This was causing it to be treated as a regular grid panel cell.

[image: Note the xtype difference]

If anyone has any suggestions for extjs sublime linters that could catch something like this, add a comment!